# What are methods having same return type as its class called?

Tags: java, oop

Is there any specific name for the methods that returns object reference of the same class it belongs to? Like

```
class A {
    public A method() { // What is such a method called?
        ...
        return objA;
    }
}
```

I would like to know what specific term is used for these methods.

Comment: It’s just a method.

Comment: It is method chaining.

Comment: What is `A` and what does `method` do? Methods don't get special names solely based on return types.

Comment: Depending on what the rest of the code is, it could be a Builder pattern. It could be a lot of different things. But in most examples the method would return `this`; what is `objA`?

Comment: There is not a term, no.  Methods either return a value or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are Singletons that are used to ensure a single static instance of a class is returned, but there is much more that goes into the singleton design pattern than just a method that returns an instance of the same class.

More on Singleton Design Pattern
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-design-pattern/

Comment: `method` is not `static`. So how would one get the instance of `A` to invoke `method`?

Comment: Correct, the method is not static, but when asking for a method that is returning an object reference, I proposed that maybe the terminology that they are looking for is something like the singleton design pattern. This is also why I stated that there's more that goes into a singleton and provided a reference to the singleton design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If the implementation finishes with:

```
return this;
```

ths class is said to have a [*fluent interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), and such a method is called a *fluent method*.

Since your implementation has:

```
return objA;
```

it suggests a new instance is created within the instance method, making this a kind of [*factory method*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which further suggests that the class is [*immutable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) and methods are available to create a new instance based wholly on `this` - aka a *copy method* - or partly on `this` - eg like `BigInteger`'s `add()` method - to make creating instances based on the state of `this` using an (possibly parameterized) action named by the name of the method more convenient; AFAIK such methods have no particular name.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google search, Looks like a normal method, but also can be referred to as `method chaining`.

Read more here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/method-chaining-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score -1):

I think you can call that a constructor.